# Clang/GCC Diagnostics not continuing after first error

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, diagnostics

I am not actually sure how to explain this but basically when I execute this (clang/gcc):

```
gcc -std=c++11 -Wall -fsyntax-only test.cpp
```

test.cpp:

```
struct tmp1
{
    tmp1() { _1 = 12; }
    int _1;
    int _2;
    bool y;
};

class tmp2
{
private:
    tmp1 in;

public:
    tmp2(const tmp1& val) : in{val}
    {
        in._1 = ""
    }
};
```

I am getting two "different" diagnostics:

GCC:

```
/Desktop/test.cpp: In constructor ‘tmp2::tmp2(const tmp1&)’:
./Desktop/test.cpp:18:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
         in._1 = ""
               ^
./Desktop/test.cpp:19:5: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
     }
     ^
```

Clang:

```
./Desktop/test.cpp:18:15: error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type
      'const char [1]'
        in._1 = ""
              ^ ~~
```

So my question is how do I get the additional diagnostic from GCC which says that there is an expcted token after '}' in clang?

Comment: You don't have an extra `}`. Clang is just doing a better job than gcc at keeping errors from propagating.

Comment: Yes but I would like it more explicit, so I guess there is no way doing that ?

Answer (score 1):

More explicit in what way? One of the problems in compilers, when you find something "that doesn't belong there", is to decide where you "continue from". It's a bit like if I tell you that "Go onto Road A, then turn left by the big oak tree onto Road B, then take the second left, and go 50 yards and you're at my house". But unknown to me, the big oaktree has been cut down because it was a danger to passing traffic, so you keep going for about a mile and a half until you find a different oak tree. Now, you won't find my house, right?

So, where do the compiler developer pick as the "next place to go on", when s/he finds the "wrong type" (a string instead of a number)? Were do we continue going? What is our "landmark" that we use to get back on track again? This is actually quite hard (the compiler I've written often fails horribly when hitting "unexpected stuff").

Or do you mean that the compiler should say "You are trying to assign a string to an `int`"? Again, the real problem here is that there is a gazillion ways that you can combine type X with type Y - string to integer, integer to string, float to string, string to float, struct to class, class to struct, class to integer, integer to class, class to class, pointer to integer, integer to pointer. Some of these are indeed distinctive errors. Others are not.

I'll be back with a refernce to where in Clang this error is printed, and maybe we can study it to figure out if it can be improved upon.

Comment: No the error messages are totally fine. Also the wrong assignment was intended to check if clang triggers an error if the semicolon is missing in the same line. Yeah the issue with "where to go next after an error occured" might be the case here so I guess there is no option to let clang simply continue after the assignment ?

Comment: I'm not THAT familiar with the actual parsing in clang (I've worked a little bit more with error output, but by no means an expert there either), but I expect it can't really know if the missing semicolon is really a missing semicolon or not...

Comment: The problem here is that if you make assumptions about "what should be there" [and that assumption goes wrong], then you end up with that horrendous stream of errors - because you missed one semicolon or something, everything else is considered "wrong", and you get 1000 errors from 20 lines of code, where your ONLY error is a missing semicolon. I believe both Clang and GCC are indeed trying their best to avoid such "we got lost and now everything is wrong".